# Finding lower bound of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the lower bound of the complex function defined in the open unit disk $|z|<1$ with $f(z)=\Re(\sqrt{1-z^4})$ ? At which point the minimum is reached.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Hint: the set of values taken by $z^4$ and the set of values taken by $z$ on the unit disk are the same. Thus your problem is the same as for $f(z)=\Re(\sqrt{1-z})$.

Comment: @JeanMarie The point of the minimum will not change with $z^4\to z$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses Yes because, $z\mapsto z^4$ is surjective (=onto) from the unit open disk onto itself (besides, not injective)